# Android XML not well formed?

Tags: xml

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background">
 <TextView  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 <Button
android:drawable="@drawable/toggleSelection"
android:layout_alignBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
 </RelativeLayout> 
 </TableLayout>'
```

Whats not well-formed about this? All elements are terminated. right?

Answer (score 3):

`RelativeLayout` is closed twice.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />    <!-- here -->
<Button
android:drawable="@drawable/toggleSelection"
android:layout_alignBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
</RelativeLayout>                         <!-- and here again -->
```

Comment: and now it says button isn't not well-formed and RelativeLayout must be followed by a > or />

Comment: @Cataroux Show your new version of the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The full XML file should be: (Remove the / at the closing bracket of RelativeLayout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background">
 <TextView  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <Button
android:drawable="@drawable/toggleSelection"
android:layout_alignBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
 </RelativeLayout> 
 </TableLayout>
```